# ListView inside ViewPager won't scroll when applying a PageTransformer

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager in which the pages contain ListViews. 
Everything works fine and my viewPAger as well as ListViews work as expected : it is possible to swipe from page to page, and the listviews scroll vertically as they should.

Now I wanted to add a PageTransformer to smooth out paging anbd I used the [ZoomOutPageTransformer](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#zoom-out) offered in the google docs.

Now I have a nice animation when swiping between views but the Lists are not scrollable anymore.

Here's the code :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.bookMenuPager);
    viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
    pagerAdapter = new MenuPagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}


class MenuPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 3; //change this as needed
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return view.equals( o );
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(position == 0){
            if(!rootMenuAdded){
                viewPager.addView(rootMenucont, 0);
                rootMenuAdded = true;
            }
            return rootMenucont; 
        }else if(position == 1){
            if(!level1MenuAdded){
                viewPager.addView(level1MenuCont, 0);
                level1MenuAdded = true;
            }
            return level1MenuCont;
        }else if(position == 2){
            if(!level2MenuAdded){
                viewPager.addView(level2MenuCont, 0);
                level2MenuAdded = true;
            }
            return level2MenuCont;
        }

        //we got a problem houston
        return null;
    }
 }
```

and the layout for a page :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/level1MenuCont"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/level1Menu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#f02bb6"
    >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What can I do to have my lists scrolling as expected ? What does the PageTransformer break in my ListView so that it wont scroll anymore? 
Is this a known bug?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 10):

I think I have found a workaround for this issue.

After some investigation, I think this only happens if you apply a `PageTransformer` that changes the coordinates of the `Views` so **they are all on top of each other** (the two example transformers do exactly this).

When you swipe in the direction such as the **NEW VIEW has a Z-index LOWER than the OLD VIEW** (normally a swipe backwards), what happens with those transformers is that the OLD VIEW is on top of the NEW VIEW, with Alpha==0, and is the one that later on gets the "ghost" touches.

Unfortunately, the solution by @ngatyrauks `bringToFront()` didn't work for me (although it definitely should).

However, I have tweaked the transformer so invisible `views` are changed its visibility to "GONE". And this does the trick.

I have yet to investigate if this Visibility change has any side effects (A `GONE` view will return `null` and zeros in layout etc, so maybe this breaks other things inside `ViewPager`), but so far it's working perfect.

I post here a tweaked `DepthPageTransformer` (the same in the docs) with these changes. Hope it helps anybody!

```
            package com.regaliz.gui.fx;

            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

            public class DepthPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

                private static final String TAG="DepthTransformer";
                private static float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;

                public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
                    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
                    Log.d(TAG, "VIew "+view+" Position: "+position);

                    if (position <= -1) { // [-Infinity,-1) ] ***

                        // RLP> I Changed to include "-1" as well: When position is -1, the view is not visible

                        // This page is way off-screen to the left.

                        view.setAlpha(0);
                        Log.d(TAG, "VIew "+view+" Position: "+position+", way left");
                        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    } else if (position <= 0) { // [ (-1,0]
                        // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
                        view.setAlpha(1);
                        view.setTranslationX(0);
                        view.setScaleX(1);
                        view.setScaleY(1);
                        if (position==0) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "View "+view+" focused now?");
                        }

                        if (view.getVisibility()!=View.VISIBLE)
                            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]

                        // Fade the page out.
                        view.setAlpha(1 - position);

                        // Counteract the default slide transition

                        // I THINK THIS IS WHAT BREAKS EVERYTHING
                        // ViewPager normally has the views one after another, but this makes all views on top

                        view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

                        // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)

                        float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
                        view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
                        view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

                        if (position==1) {

                            Log.d(TAG, "View "+view+" invisible now?");
                            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // we totally hide the view. This seems to solve focus issue

                        } else {
                            if (view.getVisibility()!=View.VISIBLE)
                                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                    } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                        // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                        view.setAlpha(0);

                        // we totally hide the view. This seems to solve focus issue
                        // I have to check for strange side-effects, but so far I found none :)

                        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        Log.d(TAG, "VIew "+view+" Position: "+position+", way right");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: absolutely unfkng beliveable this works.  I was ready to hit something.  searching for listfragment viewpager not scrolling and forgot I had added the transfrom.  wtf the examples are fails?  I'm upclicking a few more of ur answers.

Comment: haha hey thanks, it happened the same to me, this was complete madness and I had to microdebug wtf was heppening...at the end I try to avoid pagetransformers at all, I don't like the fragments are left in random state.

Comment: Works for me... for now... It's such an ugly bug! And not an easy to crack, until you discover that your touch events DID go somewhere... somewhere unexpected.

Comment: haha absolutely, it's even a potential exploit for touchjacking!

Comment: @danny117 just spent a day and a half searching the same stuff ha

Answer (score 2):

Here is the detail of the reason

> after 4.1 that the framework respects a custom child drawing order as implied Z-ordering for dispatching touch events. If your views overlap after this page transformation they may not receive touch events in the expected order on older platform versions. Check which view is receiving the touch events to be certain.
>
> If this is what you are seeing you have a few options:
>
> - Enforce the desired ordering as you add/remove child views in your PagerAdapter
> - Remove the X translation applied by the PageTransformer when a page is no longer fully visible - i.e. the "position" parameter reports a full -1 or 1.

And here is my solution

```
  public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

    if (position <= -1 || position >= 1) { // [-Infinity,-1) ] ***

        // [-Infinity,-1] or [1,+Infinity]
        // This page is way off-screen to the left or way off-screen to the right.

        view.setAlpha(0);
        view.setTranslationX(0);
        view.setScaleX(1);
        view.setScaleY(1);

    } else if (position <= 0) { // [ (-1,0]
        // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
        view.setAlpha(1);
        view.setTranslationX(0);
        view.setScaleX(1);
        view.setScaleY(1);

    } else if (position < 1) { 
        // (0,1)
        // Fade the page out.
        view.setAlpha(1 - position);
        view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

        // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)

        float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
        view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
        view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

    } 
}
```

ref link: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58918

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you got this working, but I have the same issue, with a PageDepthTransformer.  I'm using a gridview though, the scrolling works, however my subsequent fragments seem to have focus and my top level Fragment doesn't register the correct onClick() events.

My work around for this was to add global layout listener to viewPager and bring the current view to the front

```
viewPager.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        View view = viewPager.getChildAt(currentFragmentPosition);

        if (view != null) {
            view.bringToFront();
        }
    }
)};
```

This seems like hackery to me, and I haven't quite got this working on rotation.  But hopefully it might help you.

Comment: Hi! I think I have the same problem. Had a lot of hope in your solution, because in my case the focus seems stuck between the old and the new visible page. I tried this, and also calling bringToFront in other places, however that call doesnt solve the problem. Have you any other advice?

Comment: I've investigated, and found that I only have the issue if I swipe backwards: The "touch" focus remains on the view that just left the screen. It makes sense your solution: That view's z-index is bigger than the current item's. But no matter if I call bringToFront or requestFocus... The ghost touch focus remain on the other view :(